# Android multilayerd expandable listview

Tags: android, android-listview

Here i have created a expandable listview including child and parent successfully.Now i want add one more middle child into my program like this

```
parent1
     middlechild11
                child111
                child112  
      middlechild12
                child121
                child122  
  parent2
```

likewise,help me to update my code in that way please.Here is my complete code

```
  expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
  expandableListDetail =getData();
  expandableListTitle = new ArrayList(expandableListDetail.keySet());
  expandableListAdapter = new com.example.janamytri.ExpandableListAdapter(this, expandableListTitle, expandableListDetail);
  expandableListView.setAdapter(expandableListAdapter);

  expandableListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {

      @Override
      public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {

          alert();
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                  expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition) + " List Expanded.",
                  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }


  expandableListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() {

      @Override
      public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                  expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition) + " List Collapsed.",
                  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

      }
  });

  expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                  int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
          Toast.makeText(
                  getApplicationContext(),
                  expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition)
                          + " -> "
                          + expandableListDetail.get(expandableListTitle.get(childPosition)), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
          )
                  .show();
          return false;
      }
  });   

  public static HashMap getData() {
        HashMap expandableListDetail = new HashMap();

        List technology = new ArrayList();
        technology.add(arrayString);




        List entertainment = new ArrayList();

        technology.add(arrayString1);

        List science = new ArrayList();

        science.add("list1");


        expandableListDetail.put("PALAKKAD", technology);
        expandableListDetail.put("THRISSUR", entertainment);
        expandableListDetail.put("ERNAMKULAM", science);
        expandableListDetail.put("CALICUT", technology);
        expandableListDetail.put("TRIVANDRUM", entertainment);

        return expandableListDetail;
    }
```

this my ExpandableListAdapter.class

```
 public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

 private Context context;
    private List<String> expandableListTitle;
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> expandableListDetail;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> expandableListTitle,
                                 HashMap<String, List<String>> expandableListDetail) {
        this.context = context;
        this.expandableListTitle = expandableListTitle;
        this.expandableListDetail = expandableListDetail;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {
        return this.expandableListDetail.get(this.expandableListTitle.get(listPosition))
                .get(expandedListPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {
        return expandedListPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int listPosition, final int expandedListPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final String expandedListText = (String) getChild(listPosition, expandedListPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.child, null);
        }
        TextView expandedListTextView = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.childtxt);
        expandedListTextView.setText(expandedListText);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int listPosition) {
        return this.expandableListDetail.get(this.expandableListTitle.get(listPosition))
                .size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int listPosition) {
        return this.expandableListTitle.get(listPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this.expandableListTitle.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int listPosition) {
        return listPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int listPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String listTitle = (String) getGroup(listPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.
                    getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.parent, null);
        }
        TextView listTitleTextView = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.parenttxt);
        listTitleTextView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        listTitleTextView.setText(listTitle);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {
        return true;
    }

   }
```

Comment: It's better if you use one ScrollView and load all the views dynamically with animation. and you can extend that to many using ScrollView @Ashik Ashok

Comment: But here i have added only child and parent connection,but i need to add a middle child in between,and know that we should add another baseadapter,but no idea how to implement it into my program

Comment: Maximum How many child can be there in your requirement ?

Comment: 1 parent 1 middlechild 1 child likewise